# Count number of fields that match in an Array of Object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

## What I have

I have a DB in `MongoDB` like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ba531acbfed3545c51a49e"
    },
    "email": "shaswat.dharaiya@gmail.com",
    "Formats": [{
        "format": "AST-QC",
    }],
    "Series": [{
        "seq": "AST-QC - 1",
     },
     {
        "seq": "AST-QC - 2",
     },
     {
        "seq": "AST-QD - 1",
     }]
}
```

I am successfully getting the data from the `Formats` array using this query:

```
const pipeline =  [
    { $match: { "email": email } },
    { $unwind: "$Formats" },    
]
const res = await colc.aggregate(pipeline)
```

## What I want

Along with the data in the `Formats` array, I need the count of every `format` that is used by `seq` in `Series` array.

I am certain that it can be done using `$addFields`, Something like this.

```
const pipeline =  [
    { $match: { "email": email } },
    { $unwind: "$Formats" },
    { $addFields: {"Formats.count": 0} }
]
const res = await colc.aggregate(pipeline)
```

But I am not sure as to how.

I don't want to call another query using `.count()`

Comment: what count you need? `AST-QC - 1` concated number or matching string?

Comment: just the matching string from format, i.e. `AST-QC` not the concated number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `Series` array
- `$regexMatch` to search format in `seb`
- `$size` to get total elements in filtered result

```
const pipeline = [
  { $match: { email: email } },
  { $unwind: "$Formats" },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "Formats.count": {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$Series",
            cond: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$$this.seq",
                regex: "$Formats.format"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B37vAUFtOZJ)